# CSS not included in PDF attachment

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, css

I am having trouble attaching and emailing a PDF that uses Bootstrap CSS. When opening the visualforce page of the PDF myself there are no issues because the styling is loaded. But in Apex when using a Pagereference to the visualforce page, the CSS does not load. I have tried using  tags to the bootstrap cdn, using apex:stylesheets to bootstrap as a static resource, and I have inlined the entire document in  tags, but nothing helped.

I can attach code if necessary.

Thanks for your help

Edit: I don't know how much this will help, but the code is below, the "page" variable is the name of my visualforce page, which loads the styling fine if opened in a browser, but within this code, the css doesn't get loaded and the output pdf is what the page is when I comment out all of the styling.

```
    PageReference pdf = new PageReference('/apex/' + page);
    pdf.getParameters().put('id', recordId);
    pdf.getParameters().put('isPdf', 'true');

    Attachment a = new Attachment();

    Blob body;

    try{
        body = pdf.getContent();
    } catch (VisualforceException e) {
        System.debug( '### Error getting body: ' + e.getMessage() );
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Would you prefer pure speculation or something closer to "educated guesses"? If the latter, I suggest you post some code.

Comment: Edited the original post

Comment: You're going to need to post the code from one of the problematic pages. Not every VisualForce page will print as a PDF for a huge variety of reasons. Since you're using Bootstrap, I strongly suspect you may be using CSS 3 in your code. The SF PDF Render engine only supports CSS 2.1 and there's also [VisualForce components that are "unsafe" for use with PDFs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_component_behavior.htm).

Comment: Yes I am definitely using things from CSS 3, (n-th child and other things). I'll spare you reading through my VF page because it is 200+ lines of CSS and 40-50 of table rows and elements ( which are obviously not the issue). Is there any way to get around the CSS 3 issue?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way around the CSS 3 issue until SF updates the render engine they use. Rendering a PDF is like printing a file to a Postscript Printer. If you don't have the right "drivers", it's not going to print anything but garbage. At present, SF uses the Flying Saucer Render engine. Until it gets updated or they choose another one, nothing you can do. The fact we now have `pdf.getcontent()` support is huge vs a few years ago.

Comment: There was mention (about a year ago?) of a pilot for a new PDF rendering engine in Salesforce. But as the "safe harbour" statements say, you can't rely on what might happen. So if you want to stick to your current CSS you will have to pass the HTML that Visualforce generates to an external conversion service that returns the PDF equivalent. You might be lucky and find such a service or might have to write it yourself in language that has good libraries for this job if that exists.